# What are the K groups of $X_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, k-theory, topological-k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

If $X_n$ is the bouquet of n circles, then what is $K_0(X_n)$ and $K_1(X_n)$? I am super confused on how to approach this problem, since I've only seen $K_0$, $K_1$ computed for algebras, but I don't understand how the topological space $X_n$ is a C* algebra.

I imagine the solution would involve computing $K_0(\mathbb{R})$, $K_1(\mathbb{R})$ since $X_n$ is the one point compactification of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$. $K_0(\mathbb{R}) = [\mathbb{R}]$ and $K_1(\mathbb{R}) = \frac{GL(\mathbb{R})}{[GL(\mathbb{R}), GL(\mathbb{R})]}$, so would $K_0(X_n) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n}[\mathbb{R}]$, $K_1(X_n) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n}\frac{GL(\mathbb{R})}{[GL(\mathbb{R}), GL(\mathbb{R})]}$?

Comment: $K$-theory for a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ is the same as $K$-theory for the $C^*$-algebra $C_0(X)$. Usually $K$-theory of a space is written with superscripts so $K^i(X_n) = K_i(C(X_n))$ and $K^i(\mathbb{R}) = K_i(C_0(\mathbb{R}))$.

Comment: Now that this confusion of different notions of K-theory has been addressed, you can edit the question accordingly. It was an understandable confusion, so would say fix the question rather than downvote.